# error al consultar procedimiento almacenado en sql server

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, stored-procedure

Tengo una función donde recibe como parametro un id que lo envió desde postman. ese id es el que toma como parametro mi procidimiento almacenado en sql server.

procedimiento almacenado:

```
USE [Personal]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[proc_obtenerestructurajerarquicaporempleado]    Script Date: 07/08/2023 10:38:36 a. m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_obtenerestructurajerarquicaporempleado]
    @pnum_empleado INT
 AS
    DECLARE  @num_jerarquias integer;
    DECLARE  @pnum_centro integer;
    DECLARE  @jefe integer;
    DECLARE @i INT = 0;
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE #tmp_jerarquias(
            Numemp char(8),
            NumeroPuesto char(3),
            Nombrepuesto char(30) ,
            numerocentro integer,
            nombrecentro varchar(100)
        )
        SET @pnum_centro = (SELECT EMP.Centro FROM sapcatalogoempleados EMP WHERE EMP.Numemp = @pnum_empleado);
        SET @num_jerarquias = (SELECT C1.idjerarquia FROM ctl_estructurajerarquicaporarea C1 WHERE C1.numerocentro = @pnum_centro);
        INSERT INTO #tmp_jerarquias(Numemp,NumeroPuesto,Nombrepuesto,numerocentro,nombrecentro)
                    (SELECT
                        SCE.Numemp,
                        SCE.NumeroPuesto,
                        SCP.Nombre,
                        CEJPA.numerocentro,
                        CC.nombrecentro
                    FROM
                        sapcatalogoempleados SCE
                    INNER JOIN
                        ctl_estructurajerarquicaporarea CEJPA
                    ON
                        CEJPA.numerocentro = SCE.Centro
                    INNER JOIN
                        sapcatalogopuestos SCP
                    ON
                        SCP.Numero = SCE.NumeroPuesto
                    INNER JOIN
                        sapcatalogocentros CC
                    ON
                        CEJPA.numerocentro = CC.numerocentro
                    WHERE
                        SCE.Numemp = @pnum_empleado);

                    SET @jefe = 
                    (SELECT
                        CEJPA.numerogerente
                    FROM
                        ctl_estructurajerarquicaporarea CEJPA
                    WHERE
                        CEJPA.numerocentro = @pnum_centro);
            WHILE @i <= @num_jerarquias
            BEGIN
                    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tmp_jerarquias WHERE Numemp = @jefe)
                        INSERT INTO #tmp_jerarquias(Numemp,NumeroPuesto,Nombrepuesto,numerocentro,nombrecentro)
                        (SELECT
                            SCE.Numemp,
                            SCE.NumeroPuesto,
                            SCP.Nombre,
                            CEJPA.numerocentro,
                            CC.nombrecentro
                        FROM
                            sapcatalogoempleados SCE
                        INNER JOIN
                            ctl_estructurajerarquicaporarea CEJPA
                        ON
                            CEJPA.numerocentro = SCE.Centro
                        INNER JOIN
                            sapcatalogopuestos SCP
                        ON
                            SCP.Numero = SCE.NumeroPuesto
                        INNER JOIN
                            sapcatalogocentros CC
                        ON
                            CEJPA.numerocentro = CC.numerocentro
                        WHERE
                            SCE.Numemp = @jefe);

                        SET @pnum_centro = 
                        (SELECT
                            CEJPA.centroorigen
                        FROM
                            ctl_estructurajerarquicaporarea CEJPA
                        WHERE
                            CEJPA.numerocentro = @pnum_centro);
                        SET @jefe = 
                        (SELECT
                            CEJPA.numerogerente
                        FROM
                            ctl_estructurajerarquicaporarea CEJPA
                        WHERE
                            CEJPA.numerocentro = @pnum_centro);
                        
            SET @i = @i + 1
            END
                (
                    SELECT
                        TJ.Numemp AS idu_numeropersona,
                        TJ.NumeroPuesto AS idu_puesto,
                        TJ.Nombrepuesto AS nom_puesto,
                        TJ.numerocentro AS num_centro,
                        TJ.nombrecentro AS nom_centro
                    FROM 
                        #tmp_jerarquias TJ);
    END;
```

Y cuando le paso el parametro en la función, me aparece un error que dice:

> Current CallableStatement ou was not a ResultSet, but getResultList
> was called

en la variable `test = storedProcedureQuery.getResultList();`

Aquí tengo la función:

```
public List<EstructuraJerarquica> obtenerJerarquia(Long numeroPersona){
        List<EstructuraJerarquica> lista = null;

        List test = null;

        try{
            EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Personal");
            EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

            em.getTransaction().begin();
            StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedureQuery = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("proc_obtenerestructurajerarquicaporempleado");

            storedProcedureQuery.registerStoredProcedureParameter("pnum_empleado", Long.class, ParameterMode.IN);
            storedProcedureQuery.setParameter("pnum_empleado", numeroPersona);

            storedProcedureQuery.execute();

            test = storedProcedureQuery.getResultList();

        }catch (Exception ex){
            log.info("ERROR->" + ex.getMessage());
        }


        return test;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

La función execute, devuelve true si el resultado es un "resultset" y falso si es una actualización o cualquier otra actualización sin salida. Estaría bien, que hicieras un if para comprobar su retorno antes de hacer la llamada a getResultList.
Además, viendo el error, lo que te ocurre es que el procedimiento no está devolviendo un ResultSet.

Échale un vistazo a la siguiente URL:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58598421/current-callablestatement-ou-was-not-a-resultset-but-getresultlist-was-called